# How to select a single node from an Xml Document in Powershell where the XPath contains a variable?

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I'm hitting a brick wall trying to detect whether a node already exists while manipulating an XML file in Powershell.

Unfortunately the XmlDocument I'm processing uses default namespaces which I think confuses things.

Here's a subset of the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration" xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions" xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu">
    <editor name="MyExtension">
      <installpath xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration">C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\MyExtension</installpath>
      <configuration xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration">Editor\Configuration\editor.config</configuration>
      <vdir xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration">MyExtension</vdir>
    </editor>
  </editors>
</Configuration>
```

I want to check whether the editor node with the name attribute set to "MyExtension" exists in Powershell and add it if it doesn't.

Adding it is fine (apart from some namespace shenanigans) but detecting it has me stumped.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
# Update System.config
$filename = $tridionInstallLocation + '\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration\System.config'
$conf = [xml](gc $filename)

[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsm = new-object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $conf.NameTable
$nsm.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration")

# Editor
$xpath = "//x:Configuration/x:editors/x:editor[name=MyExtension]"
# $existingModelNode = $conf.SelectSingleNode($xpath, $nsm)
$existingModelNode = Select-Xml $conf -XPath $xpath
Write-Host $existingEditorNode # This is blank always
if($existingEditorNode -eq $null)
{
    $editors = [System.Xml.XmlElement]$conf.Configuration.editors
    $myElement = $conf.CreateElement("editor", $nsm.LookupNamespace("x"))
    $nameAttr = $myElement.SetAttribute("name", $name)
    $myElement.InnerXml = "<installpath xmlns='http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration'>" + $editorInstallLocation + "</installpath><configuration xmlns='http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration'>" + $editorConfigFile + "</configuration><vdir xmlns='http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration'>" + $name + "</vdir>"
    $editors.AppendChild($myElement)
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Editor node already exists in System.config with name $name, skipping"
}
```

I've been going round in circles trying various different methods. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Incomplete sample(editors start-node missing) and I get namespacemanager error(which I didn't have time to figure out now). But your xpath looks wrong. only the first node `configuration` has namespace defined. Also, `name` is an attribute, which makes it `[@name="MyExtension"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this should work:

```
@($config.Configuration.editors.editor.name) -contains 'MyExtension'
```

Comment: Boom! Thanks. Wish I could get the last 2 hours of my life back.. Do you know any good resources for working xml in this way in Powershell?

Comment: Once it's cast to [XML] in Powershell, you can navigate the nodes using dot notation, the same as you would properties of a PS Object.